# Keras categorical-crossentropy vs binary-crossentropy

Tags: keras, loss-function

i've searched the difference between categorical cross-entropy and binary cross-entropy in keras (as loss functions), but i can't find a complete and convincing answer.
In a multi label classification problem, which one should be used?
What are the formulas for each one?

thanks in advance

Answer (score 2):

Do you want a multilabel with only one correct label or with many correct labels?

- Use `'categorical_crossentropy'` for a single correct label. Good combined with `'softmax'`, for instance
- Use `'binary_crossentropy'` for many correct labels (independent labels). Good combined with `'sigmoid'`.

Comment: the definition of multilabel classification is that one value can have more than one label, if i understood well. The first option seem to be mutliclass classification, right? But my question was : ok, Why? how keras compute each one?

Comment: You can see it in keras source code. https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/r1.12/tensorflow/python/keras/backend.py